# Can the Jacobian of a Neural Network be Full Column Rank?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, math, computational-learning-theory

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be the input data space and $\mathcal{Y}$ be the output data space.

$f: \mathcal{X} \to \mathcal{Y}$ is a function represented by some Neural Network.

Is it possible to to check if the Jacobian $J_{f}:=\left(\frac{\partial f_{i}}{\partial x_j}\right)$ is full Column rank? or are there some conditions (like specific activation function) we can assume on the Neural network to make it full Column rank?

Also can it be safely applied to CNNs and not only ANN? (because I think CNN can not be treated as in vector space)